# What is the equivalent of Solaris's cu command in Linux?

Tags: linux, solaris

What is the equivalent of Solaris's cu command in Linux?

Answer (score 2):

It's called [cu](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cu)

Comment: in linux there is no manual page for cu command ..(cu coomand is not there in linux)

Comment: That link is to a Linux manual page for cu.  You don't see it because you haven't installed the package yet, but Debian and Ubuntu both have cu packages.

Answer (score 1):

`cu` is part of the *UUCP* suite. So look for for a package named `uucp`, `tuucp` or `taylor-uucp` if `cu` is not available as a seperate package for your distribution.